# After using Google fast login, the API works but when redirect to page, it got error with Index out of range

Tags: asp.net-mvc

When I use this one to log in via **Google API**, after login success then I received the error Index out of range with the red line in `if (s[0].ToString() == "Admin")`. Can anyone help me this check. And what do I need to change in this code.

```
if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    var user = User.Identity;
    ApplicationDbContext context = new ApplicationDbContext();
    var UserManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context));
    var s = UserManager.GetRoles(user.GetUserId());
    if (s[0].ToString() == "Admin")
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`GetRoles()` returns an `IList`. This list may or may not contain items. If it does not contain any roles, its length would be 0, so accessing a member of it at index 0 will fail.

You could use

```
if(s.Contains("Admin")) 
{
    return true;          
}
return false;
```

Also: You cannot be sure, that even if the user is an admin, that the returned roles collection has "Admin" at the index 0. What if it is not ordered alphabetically or if there is a role before Admin called "_Admin". You code would return a false result.

Comment: I will try this. I dont think to this situation whether should i check Admin using index. Thanks bro